# Possible incompatibility with enumitem

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

If I compile the following:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[1.]
    \item This is the first
    \item This is the second
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I get the error message:

`Package enumitem Error: 1. undefined.`

But if I compile the following:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
% \usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[1.]
    \item This is the first
    \item This is the second
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

It works fine. What am I missing when I load `enumitem`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to use the `shortlabels` option to have compatibility with the `enumerate`-like scheme for labels:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[1.]
    \item This is the first
    \item This is the second
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

but I would suggest to load only `enumitem` with the `shortlabels` option:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[1.]
    \item This is the first
    \item This is the second
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina `shortlabels` option saves a lot  of writing!