# How to list items like this: (i), (ii), (iii) etc?

Tags: lists, enumerate

If you have mathematic theorems that have more than one conclusion how do you list them this way:

> (i) First conclusion here
>
> (ii) Second conclusion here
>
> (iii) Third conclusion here

effectively? I do it manually but it doesn't look good. Enumerate doesn't work either.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

### Which one is best?

See daleif answer to learn more about advantages of `enumitem` over `enumerate`.

### `enumitem` package (Option 1)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}   
     
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
        \item First item
        \item Second item
        \item Third item
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: example screenshot]

### `enumerate` package (Option 2)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}   
    
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[(i)]
        \item First item
        \item Second item
        \item Third item
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

### `beamer` package (Option 3)

This is only of interest, *if you are creating a presentation*.

**Note** that if you're using the **beamer** class, you don't need to load any extra package (the enumerate package is actually automatically loaded):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
```

```latex
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{enumerate}[(i)]
            \item First item
            \item Second item
            \item Third item
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As mentioned is the comments, enumitem is not compatible with the beamer class unless you use the [shortlabels] option, as explained here: [Possible incompatibility with enumitem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58852/possible-incompatibility-with-enumitem)

Comment: Can the left paranthesis for all start from the same location?

Answer (score 21):

Here's a solution that doesn't require loading a package. Instead, the solution works by modifying two LaTeX macros, `\labelenumi` and `\theenumi`. The former determines how the item's "label" is shown, the latter affects how an item's number will be displayed in a cross-reference (arabic, roman, with or without parentheses, etc).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\labelenumi{(\roman{enumi})}
\renewcommand\theenumi\labelenumi
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First
\item Second \label{item:second}
\item Third
\end{enumerate}
Here's a cross-reference to item~\ref{item:second}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be noted that this has the benefit that you don't have to provide an option to `enumerate` each time you want the same kind of list.

Comment: I tried your solution, it does not work with me. any suggestions?

Comment: @Mohamed - An observation such as "it does not work for me" is simply unactionable. *What exactly* isn't working? Are you getting warning and/or error messages? Which document class do you employ? Please be much more specific. Aside: I just re-ran the code shown above, and nearly four years since posting it, it still produces the result shown in the screenshot above...

Answer (score 15):

Just to elaborate on Hugos answer, use the `enumitem` package it is a great package for configuring lists.

Manually just once use

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
```

It might be an idea to load `enumitem` with the `shortlabels` option:

```
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
```

Then you can simply use

```
\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
```

A great feature is that if you now use `\item\label{item:1}` and then use `\ref{item:1}` then you get `(i)`, that is the formatting is included! This is also configurable, see the `enumitem` manual.

Also lists can be resumed.

If you are writing a book using say, theorems, there are also general methods to add list configurations into theorems (I typically use `etoolbox` to do that). This means that inside theorem I just write `\begin{enumerate}` and we then control the appearance of `enumerate` inside theorem from the preamble.

Then the only time we explicitly need to set options on `enumerate` inside a theorem, would be if we have two types of lists in the theorem, say, one specifying conditions and then one listing subsequent conclusions. In such a case I'd let the conditions follow a different pattern.

Comment: You mean, `\label=`?

Comment: At @pushpen.paul what do you mean? No here `\label` is an option to enumerate and has nothing to do with `\label` (sort of), please read the enumitem manual

Comment: @daleif Why asterisk is needed in \roman*?

Comment: @adosar see the enumitem manual, roman normally takes an argument

Answer (score -2):

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*.]
    \item one
    \item two
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) In what way does your answer differ from the [one of daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222412/184389)? Moreover, it is unusable as is since it is not a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/184389).