# How to use noitemsep with roman numerals in enumerate

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

The following code works

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}          % line 2
%\usepackage{enumitem}          % line 3

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[(i)]          % line 6
%\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep]   % line 7
\item one
\item two
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

and gives me something like

> i. one
>
> ii. two

But if I want to make the separation smaller, I would like to use enumitem package (following [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures#Customizing_lists)). However, I cannot use `[(i)]` when I use package `enumitem`. How can I get both of these features.

Comment: With `enumitem` you can use `label=(\roman*)` instead of `(i)`. About `enumerate`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/519982/134574.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer the Phelype Oleinik's way, using the `enumitem` package:

You can use `noitemsep` as an environment option:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{enumerate}          % line 2
\usepackage{enumitem}          % line 3

\begin{document} 
   \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*),noitemsep]          % line 6
      \item one
      \item two
    \end{enumerate} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: It's ansered in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222408/how-to-list-items-like-this-i-ii-iii-etc

Comment: I'd say the earlier answer addresses the `label=(\roman*)` part, but not the `noitemsep` part.

Comment: it's my fault, the link where is the posted answer is:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119919/no-spacing-between-enumerated-items-with-usepackageenumerate

Answer (score 3):

With the `[shortlabels]` option, the `enumitem` package allows to write the very simple and user-friendly syntax of the `enumerate` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem} 

\begin{document} 
   \begin{enumerate}[(i),noitemsep]  
      \item one
      \item two
    \end{enumerate} 
\end{document}
```

[image]